# JavaScript Toggle Display

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I'm trying to use vanilla JavaScript to toggle `display: none` and `display: block` on elements with the same class. It mostly works, but for some reason you need to click the button twice for it to work and it's eating away at me. The code and a link to CodePen is below.

The HTML:

```
<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
<div class="d">d</div>

<button onclick="toggle('a')">Toggle A</button>
<button onclick="toggle('b')">Toggle B</button>
<button onclick="toggle('c')">Toggle C</button>
<button onclick="toggle('d')">Toggle D</button>
```

The JS:

```
function toggle(div) {
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName(div);

    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      if(divs[i].style.display === "block") {
        divs[i].style.display="none";
      }
      else {
        divs[i].style.display="block";
      }
    }

}
```

The Demo:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/terf/pen/LjuCh)

Comment: You cannot necessarily get information by testing for properties of the `Element.style` Object, unless that property is set specifically. You cannot see CSS that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: block;` to the CSS definition for the DIV.

Comment: So it knows to toggle from block to none on the first click.

Comment: Would have to be set in inline style, or by JavaScript.

Comment: Well, at least on Chrome, it works perfectly if it's set in the CSS.  That might not be a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

add the style attribute to the divs..

```
<div class="a" style="display:block">a</div>
<div class="b" style="display:block">b</div>
<div class="c" style="display:block">c</div>
<div class="d" style="display:block">d</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this instead:

```
<div class='a'>a</div>
<div class='b'>b</div>
<div class='c'>c</div>
<div class='d'>d</div>

<input type='button' id='aT' value='Toggle A' />
<input type='button' id='bT' value='Toggle B' />
<input type='button' id='cT' value='Toggle C' />
<input type='button' id='dT' value='Toggle D' />
```

Put external JavaScript tag in `<head>` for caching:

```
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function C(n){
  if(doc.getElementsByClassName){
    return doc.getElementsByClassName(n);
  }
  var t = doc.getElementsByTagName('*'), a = [];
  for(var i=0,l=t.length; i<l; i++){
    if(t[i].className.match(new RegExp('\\b'+n+'\\b'))){
      a.push(t[i]);
    }
  }
  return a;
}
function getStyleProp(elem, prop){
  return getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue(prop) || elem.currentStyle[prop];
}
function toggle(elem){
  elem.style.display = getStyleProp(elem, 'display').match(/^block$/i) ? 'none' : 'block';
  return elem;
}
var btns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
for(var i=0,l=btns.length; i<l; i++){
  (function(i){
    var b = btns[i], c = C(b);
    E(b+'T').onclick = function(){
      for(var n=0,q=c.length; n<q; n++){
        toggle(c[n]);
      }
    }
  })(i);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `var divs = document.getElementsByClassName(div);` will only return one element because there is only one element with that class.

```
<div id="blocks'>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="d">d</div>
</div>

function toggle(div) {
  var divs = document.getElementById('blocks');
  var ele = blocks.getElementsByTagName("div');
  var sty = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
      sty = ( ele[i].className.indexOf( div ) ) ? 'block' : 'none';
       ele[i].style.display = sty;
      }
    }
}
```