# change view from list to grid after click

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I've created list view using bootstrap 5:

```
 <div class="col">
    Click to switch to grid/list
    </div>
```

and here I've content list:

```
<div class="row mt-3 list">
list view
...
.....
.......
</div>
```

and here I've content grid:

```
<div class="row mt-3 grid d-none">
grid view
...
.....
.......
</div>
```

List view is enabled by default.

Can anyone help me if I click **Click to switch to grid/list** then remove tag from grid d-none and add  d-none to tag list ?

and again when I click then rewrite changes ?

I try somelike this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click to switch to grid/list</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

But this not work for me and I cannot get effect which I try and with this code not possible rewrite changes.  I read every questions/answears here   but none suit me and I can't implement it to my solution.

Comment: So you want it so that the first click will hide the list view and show the grid view, and the next click will hide the grid view and show the list view again?

Comment: Yes @letu thats it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript Toggle Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415139/javascript-toggle-display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, it toggles the visibility between the two using style.display

```
    <button id="toggleButton">Toggle View</button>

    <div class="row mt-3 list">
    list view
    ...
    .....
    .......
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3 grid">
    grid view
    ...
    .....
    .......
    </div>        
    
    <script>
        const toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggleButton");
        const list = document.querySelector(".list");
        const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
        grid.style.display = "none";
        toggleButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (grid.style.display === "none") {
            grid.style.display = "block";
            list.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            grid.style.display = "none";
            list.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
    </script>
```